# Django query with values() where class contains one to many foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models

If a class has a one to many relationship, and is queried with other attributes from the class that are just fields (TextFields for example), is it possible to complete this in a values() query, and will it result in a list of nested dictionaries?

For example (where you would want to get the value for 'a_field' for all related 'another_class' objects):

```
class some_class(models.Model):
    some_text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class another_class(models.Model):
    a_field = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    many    = models.ForeignKey(some_class, models.SET_NULL, db_column='some_class_id', related_name='another_class_things', blank=True, null=True)


query_set = ['some_text', 'another_class_things__a_field']
dict_list = some_class.objects.values(*query_set).filter(id='1234').first()
```

where you would normally access all the related values with:

```
obj          = some_class()
sub_obj_list = obj.another_class_things.all()
```